# Video editor with recording options

Tags: lubuntu, microphone, video-editor

I'm searching for a video editor which would also allow recording from microphone. 
It must run in Lubuntu and include 3 features which would work simultaneously:

1. seeing the video (a moving picture, of course)
2. seeing and hearing the original audio track
3. seeing and editing the audio track(s) which I record myself from my microphone

I've already installed many video editors, but not any of them allows me to record my own voice, neither from a built-in microphone, nor from a plug-in one.

I'm not very familiar with all the complicated Linux stuff, so if you do answer, please don't make it too complicated.

Comment: I would use Audacity to record (and modify) the audio, then import it into a video editor such as OpenShot or Kdenlive. Importing it into a separate layer will preserve the video/audio in the other layers.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, pretty much the best video-editing program available is [Kdenlive](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kdenlive/):
[image: Kdenlive Screenshot]

There is [Avidemux](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/avidemux/) as well:
[image: Avidemux screenshot]

And for Audio recording + editing, [Audacity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity/) is simply brilliant:
[image: Audacity Screenshot]

If  you have problems recording, you may need to select your input device. Install the program needed:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

You can then open it with `pavucontrol`, and edit the input devices:
[image]

The input device that has the green tick next to it selected is the one that is set to default, so is likely to be the one used by the program.

Comment: Does this mean that one can record from a microphone in Kdenlive? I have got it installed, but could not record - so does that mean, that the problem is not Kdenlive, but something else?

Comment: pavucontrol doens't work on my PC, but I've got other audio control stuff, and I've tried choosing different microphones, ubuntu recognizes them, i can record from microphone in audacity.
Of course I've used Audacity before, it is very useful indeed - but the thing is, as I said previously, that I need to see the video while recording - simultaneously. As I am dubbing videos, it is a necessary option.

Thanks for telling me about Avidemux, maybe that will do (although I don't have much hope)

Comment: If you can record from microphone in Kdenlive, then, I beg you, do make a screenshot of where that mysterious record button is - I'm already annoying of searching for it, I think it doesn't exist -_-

Comment: Oh, I've discovered, that I already have Avidemux installed as well! Failed with microphone recording there, too! Maybe you misunderstood me? The 3 features listed in my question have to run _simultaneously_, in _one_ _program_. When dubbing, if you have the video in one window and the audio in another, then you're in trouble, the work is going to steal a hideous amount of time, and that is unaffordable for me.

Comment: With kdenlive you should be able to do it in 'Record Monitor' - select 'FFmpeg', and only to record 'Audio'. It should work. For that sort of thing, I just use VLC + Audacity,  [like in this bad example for a holiday video of lion taming](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BVhvX.png) - that's is I think how I did half of my GCSE ICT work... Starting the audio recording, dubbing various videos, then editing and exporting the audio is fairly easy to do. Audio recording seems a bit weird in Kdenlive sadly...

Comment: alright, 'mysterious record button' found!!! so the thing was to choose ffmpeg. Thanks for telling me about it!!! i myself would have never figured that out, because the options combination seems to be endless, and it looks like only one of them works. totally user-unfriendly. user-foe :(

Comment: but it looks like you cannot see anything while recording. neither the video, nor your own audio track being recorded. i need this so i would know at which exact moment comes what. i cannot waste time on clicking 'pause' in different windows, a speech, misplaced even by a second, is already damn misplaced! So is it true that you cannot see all that necessary stuff, and there are no programs in linux which allow you to, or am I just 'blind' again?

Comment: That may be true - you could use [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/about/) to run a Windows video editor though....

Answer (score 5):

KdenLive is what you need.

Grab the latest version (17.04.1) [from the official website](https://kdenlive.org/).

Open it up. It will look like this (note my OS is Ubuntu GNOME, not Lubuntu):

[image]

Click Settings and Configure KdenLive:

[image]

Click Capture on the left, and the FFMPEG tab. Ensure your camera is enabled and set to the right modes. You will probably have to check the "Capture Audio" box, and possibly set the device (green boxes):

[image]

Click Monitor and Show Record Control, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
then <kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

On the clip monitor tab, up pops a cute lil recording menu.

[image]

Right click on the black monitor box, and select "Overlay current audio waveform":

[image]

The waveform appears:

[image]

<sup>As an aside: why do you need this to be one tool? It sounds a little bit borderline "XY problem". You're asking us the equivalent of how to cut the roof off your car, when what you actually need is a pickup truck. If I know your end goal, there might be a better path.</sup>

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  I need this feature because I want to do YouTube tutorials. For that I usually have multiple images and some videos that I need to cut together and then I put my voice over it. Often each picture covers one topic and I like to record my voice for each picture seperatly. Then I can extend the duration of the image according to my voice. I find this much easier then switiching between the video editor and something like Audacity. Do you think I should do things in a different way?

Comment: I also create you tube videos. Mine is a little different because I'm recording animations which I'm making in PowerPoint. As it happens, I would record the audio on my iPhone microphone - it was the clearest - and then edit it together. I think I would suggest you use gcuview for the video and audio and then kdenlive to edit it. If you are able, write a script so you have everything you want to say in one recording. This also means your voice will change less between clips if you move around...

Answer (score 0):

I like Kazam. Very user friendly, and it will do all the criteria. I found 
this website to tell you more about it's capabilities:http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-create-screencast-videos-kazam-screencaster-linux/.